# Dynamic column name in return type

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table with the multiple columns in it. I want to return the details 
of the table by call function. In the following I have created table with 
some records and have also created function to return the result of select
statement.

**Table**:

```
create table for_test
(
cola varchar(10),
colb varchar(10),
name varchar(20),
address varchar(50)
);
```

**Inserting records**:

```
insert into for_test values('A101','B101','SAM','Munich');
insert into for_test values('A102','B102','AMC','Belgium');
insert into for_test values('A103','B103','MAM','Shanghai');
insert into for_test values('A104','B104','KOU','Dhaka');
```

**Note**: In the function I have passed one paramenter which called as `p_columnname` in 
which I will pass the column name between `cola or colb`.

IF I pass the column name `cola` it has to return the result like `cola colb name`.

IF I pass the column name `colb` it has to return the result like `colb cola name`.

**Function**:

```
create or replace function for_test
(
    p_columnname varchar(20)
)

RETURNS TABLE
(
    _cola varchar(10),
    _colb varchar(10),
    _name varchar(20)
) AS
$$

DECLARE 
    v_details varchar;
    v_query varchar;
BEGIN
    IF p_columnname = 'cola' THEN

        v_details := 'cola,colb,name';

    ELSIF p_columnname = 'colb' THEN

        v_details := 'colb,cola,name';

    ELSE
        v_details := 'cola,colb,name';

    END IF;

    v_query := 'SELECT '|| v_details ||' from for_test';

    RAISE INFO '%',v_query;

    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE v_query;

END;

$$

LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

--IF I pass columnname = 'cola' this will show:

```
SELECT * FROM for_test('cola');

_cola  _colb  _name
------------------- 
 A101   B101   SAM
 A102   B102   AMC
 A103   B103   MAM
 A104   B104   KOU
```

--IF I pass columnname = 'colb' this will show:

```
SELECT * FROM for_test('colb');

_cola  _colb  _name
------------------- 
 B101   A101   SAM
 B102   A102   AMC
 B103   A103   MAM
 B104   A104   KOU
```

**Question**: How to change the column name in the `RETURN TABLE TYPE` 
 if the input column changes from `cola` to `colb`?

Comment: what about this `select _cola as _colb,_colb as _cola,_name from for_test('colb');`

Comment: @WingedPanther, What if there is long column(s) list? What should I use `column list` like you used or `*`? Which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically change the return type by creating `type` like below

```
create type colb_a as (colb varchar(10), --_colb comes first
    _cola varchar(10),
    _name varchar(20))
```

and

```
create type cola_b as (cola varchar(10), -- _cola Comes first
    _colb varchar(10),
    _name varchar(20))
```

In the *TYPE* you can define the column name that should come when you call a function or whatever

and create your function with this

```
create or replace function for_test
(
    _retType anyelement,p_columnname varchar(20)
)

RETURNS  setof anyelement AS


 ...
 ...

LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

So you need to Call the function like this :

```
select * from for_test(NULL::cola_b,'cola');

select * from for_test(NULL::colb_a,'colb');
```